Error while vectorizing a function containing while loop
I have the follwing code:
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

@np.vectorize
def simulation(_):
    numRolls = 0
    diff = 0
    prevRoll = -999999
    while True:
        roll = random.randint(1, 7)
        print(prevRoll, roll)
        numRolls += 1
        diff = np.abs(roll - prevRoll)
        if diff == 1:
            break
        else:
            prevRoll = roll
    
    return numRolls

If I remove the decorator, the code works perfectly fine. But using the np.vectorize, it seems the while loop continues to run even if it hits break, and then when it hits break again, the loop stops, which seems really odd. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and what the solution would be? I need to have the function vectorized to find the mean.

Be aware that np.vectorize is only provided for convenience, not speed. It does not actually vectorize the loop based on the definition provided by Numpy developers themselves. It basically use a CPython-like loop internally, hence the performance information provided in the documentation.

@JérômeRichard thanks for the info, I was checking performance of same code with for loop and np.vectorize; the performance of both are clearly same (sometime np.vectorize is taking slightly more time to run, actually). In any case, I am using jit to compile now.

Which JIT are you talking about by the way? Please note the CPython's JIT only brings a very small speed up compared to what can be achieved.

@JérômeRichard I don't know much specifics, I am using jit from numba. But it's really fast, as far I check, working like 1000 (not in literal sense) times faster while calculating mean.

Ok, Numba is fine here. This is a good use-case. Cython (with type annotations) can also be used too (avoiding the runtime compilation overhead and a runtime dependency).

You have the answer in the docs

If otypes is not specified, then a call to the function with the first
argument will be used to determine the number of outputs. The results
of this call will be cached if cache is True to prevent calling the
function twice. However, to implement the cache, the original
function must be wrapped which will slow down subsequent calls, so
only do this if your function is expensive.

You need to set otypes with the return types
@np.vectorize(otypes=[int])
def simulation(_):
    ...


Thanks Guy!!! I was checking docs just before I saw the answer! It works now.
